# How to prevent the repetition of code suggest for Python in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pylance

I am using VSCode for writing Python code in a Jupyter Notebook. The relevant extensions installed are Python, Pylance and Jupyter. The problem occurs when I am coding, VSCode will give two same suggestion in the box. It looks like this:
[image]

How can I remove the duplicated code suggestion?

Comment: This may be some unknown error between pylance and jupyter.
After adding "python.pylanceLspNotebooksEnabled": true to the settings.json, it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Jupyter extension to pre-release version.

[image]